# I can't seem to find images for my HTML website?

Tags: html, css

I'm building my first website using HTML and CSS on Visual Studio 2019, using a YouTube tutorial as well as my own small amount of knowledge. Except when I went to insert an image using:

```
<img src="image.jpg">
```

it doesn't find it.
I have also tried using the image source path thingy using:

```
<img src="C:/Users/Josh/Documents/HTML/BusinessWebsite/image.jpg">
```

but this also doesn't work. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your project folder?

Comment: Take a look at using relative paths: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: I'd recommend to use Visual Studio Code since using Visual Studio for a static HTML page is like using Dragons Breath to light a cigarette.

Comment: Are you running a web server or are you just opening an HTML file in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

Use the relative paths. The path is taken from where you have your html file. Like when you're moving between folders in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should have provided some more information, because your syntax seems to be perfect. There you can try out two things :

1. The first thing I can figure out that might have gone here would be that your image extension might not be correct, which means it might be something else than jpg(may be jpeg or png).
2. Use relative paths.

Example
[image]